# If else for main menu

Tags: routes, navigation

im trying to do a if else statement for the main menu, i have something like this but i dont know where to begin.

```
<?php if ( !$is_front ) : ?>
function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output .= l('<h2>'. check_plain($link['title']) .'</h2>', $link['href'], $link);
  }
  return $output;
}

<?php else: ?>

function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output .= l(''. check_plain($link['title']) .'', $link['href'], $link);
  }
  return $output;
}
<?php endif ?>
```

as you can see i want the tags on the front page and if it isnt then i want the tags to disappear.

Comment: Where are you using that code?

Comment: template.php with the other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few tweaks this is the correct way to do it.

```
function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
    $output = '';
    $opening_tag = '<h2>';
    $closing_tag = '</h2>';

    if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
      $opening_tag = '';
      $closing_tag = '';
    }

    foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output[] = l($link['title'], $link['href']);
    }
    return $opening_tag . implode($closing_tag . $opening_tag, $output) . $closing_tag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where/when this function is called, but here's your code with some fixes:

```
function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
    $output = '';
    $prefix = drupal_is_front_page() ? '' : '<h2>';
    $suffix = drupal_is_front_page() ? '' : '</h2>';

    foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
        $output .= l($prefix.check_plain($link['title']).$suffix, $link['href'], $link);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this but when I add it into my template.php file the menu doesn't input any of the tags it remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

The list of the variables passed to that theme function is listed in the documentation for [theme_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7); `$variables["is_front"]` is not passed to `theme_links()` or `theme_links__system_main_menu()`.

There is a misunderstanding here: template.php is a file containing functions used by Drupal when using the theme containing that file; it should not contain any `<?php else: ?>`.

The code you should use is, roughly, the following one (it is not optimized):

```
function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $output = '';
  $opening_tag = '';
  $closing_tag = '';

  if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $opening_tag = '<h2>';
    $closing_tag = '</h2>';
  }

  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output .= l($opening_tag . check_plain($link['title']) . $closing_tag, $link['href'], $link);
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I tested your function also and nothing shows, im pretty positive im inputting the function correctly

Comment: Did you define the theme function in `hook_theme()`; I am not sure you should, as I have never understood if themes need to declare their theme functions.

Comment: Also, if you edited the copy of the file installed in your Drupal site, it is probable the theme function is not automatically found. Even in the case you don't need to implement `hook_theme()`, you need to do something to let Drupal see there is a theme function more; normally changing the default theme, and then setting back the old one should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the if check *inside* the theme function, where it is probably $variables['is_front'] and if that doesn't work, use [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).

The $is_front variable is only available inside a template file, not template.php.